# Function in a Function Errors

Tags: php, function, date

```
function Sign1(){
    $check = array(
        '23-03-2014' => 'saturday 22 may',
        '17-05-2014' => 'friday 16 may'
    );
    Dateoption();
}
function Sign2(){
    $check = array(
        '10-02-2014' => 'monday 10 feb',
        '15-02-2014' => 'friday 15 feb',
        '14-03-2014' => 'friday 14 march'
    );
    Dateoption();
}
function Dateoption(){
    $now = time();
    $result = array();
    foreach($check as $date => $text) {
        if($now  <= strtotime($date)) {
            $result[] = $text;
        }
    }
    $html = '';
    foreach($result as $v) {
        $html .= '<option>'.$v.'</option>';
    }
    return $html;
}
$Content= '
<div class="content">
    I am signing up for the following date:<br />
    <select name="date[0]">
        '. Sign1() .'
    </select>
    <select>
        '. Sign2() .'
    </select>
</div>
';
echo $Content;
```

---

Why is this not working? It is going wrong @ foreach($check as $date => $text) { but what do i have to change to let this work. I'm doing this So i only have to type the function once instead of copy pasting it everywhere.

Comment: You start with "And again", which is a strange way to start a question. Also, what is it supposed to do, what does it actually do, and why do the dates in Sign1 have no relationship to their descriptions?

Comment: Please add tags to your question. Especially about the language involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to do with variable scope. Dateoption cannot see the $check variable. The [php documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) describes this as: `However, within user-defined functions a local function scope is introduced. Any variable used inside a function is by default limited to the local function scope.`

You need to pass $check as a parameter to the Dateoption method.

```
function Sign1(){
    $check = array(
        '23-03-2014' => 'saturday 22 may',
        '17-05-2014' => 'friday 16 may'
    );
    return Dateoption($check);
}
function Sign2(){
    $check = array(
        '10-02-2014' => 'monday 10 feb',
        '15-02-2014' => 'friday 15 feb',
        '14-03-2014' => 'friday 14 march'
    );
    return Dateoption($check);
}
function Dateoption($check){
    $now = time();
    $result = array();
    foreach($check as $date => $text) {
        if($now  <= strtotime($date)) {
            $result[] = $text;
        }
    }
    $html = '';
    foreach($result as $v) {
        $html .= '<option>'.$v.'</option>';
    }
    return $html;
}
$Content= '
<div class="content">
    I am signing up for the following date:<br />
    <select name="date[0]">
        '. Sign1() .'
    </select>
    <select>
        '. Sign2() .'
    </select>
</div>
';
echo $Content;
```

Comment: Yeah we are in the right way now, but there is nothing showing up in the select sections? Do you know anything about that?

Comment: Sign1 and Sign2 also need to return the output of Dateoption. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Aaaahhh like that! Thnxs man! This helps me a lot! (Yeah i know i'm sometimes a little bit noobisch but thats why i ask and i learn a lot about it!)